# How to show line number and file on tracing events?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

How to print what source `line!` and `file!` a trace log originated from with [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) and [tracing-subscriber](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-subscriber)?

The code I'm working with is well prepared and contains lots of log prints, which is good, but most of them are not very descriptive:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tracing = "0.1.35"
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.11"
```

```
tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();

// ...

if let Err(e) = important_work.await {
    tracing::info!(" {:?}", &e);
};
```

And the console prints only show module and error message, not where the code failed. When I replaced it with:

```
pub struct CustomLayer;

impl<S> Layer<S> for CustomLayer
where
    S: tracing::Subscriber,
{
    fn on_event(
        &self,
        event: &tracing::Event<'_>,
        _ctx: tracing_subscriber::layer::Context<'_, S>,
    ) {
         println!("{level}  name={:?}", event.metadata().name());
         for field in event.fields() {
            println!("  field={}", field);
         }
      }
}

   // Snip to main()

   tracing_subscriber::registry().with(CustomLayer).init();
```

I was able to get the file and line in `event.metadata().name())` but then all error messages are turned into just the string "message". There is probably a simpler way of enabling printing of line numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customize the formatter [as specified in the documentation](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/index.html#customizing-formatters). Some of the options are [`with_file()`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Format.html#method.with_file) and [`with_line_number()`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Format.html#method.with_line_number):

```rust
tracing_subscriber::fmt()
    .event_format(
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::format()
            .with_file(true)
            .with_line_number(true)
    )
    .init();
```

Example output (without colors ):

```
2022-07-12T06:05:35.654279Z  INFO playground: src/main.rs:16: abc
```

You can of course use additional options as you wish.

Comment: These methods are available on `tracing_subscriber::fmt()` directly: `tracing_subscriber::fmt().with_file(true).with_line_number(true).init()` should be a bit more succinct.

Comment: If your Cargo project has dependency on another crate in the local file system (for example, `another-crate = {path="../another/crate"}` in the `Cargo.toml`) , Every call to the function `with_file(...)` in another crate  exposes the full path of the crate file in a log event, you might need to avoid that for security concern.